Remember Composable State even if the code location where remember is called is not invoked during a recomposition
How can we ensure the persistent retention of a state in a Composable function, even if the invocation of the code containing the remember statement is not triggered during a recomposition?
Taking into account the given scenario, what would be the correct approach to maintain the showTask state (after it has been set to false), despite the count being reset to zero upon clicking the "Clear water count" button?
@Composable
fun WaterCounter(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Column(modifier = modifier.padding(16.dp)) {
        var count by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
        if (count > 0) {
            var showTask by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
            if (showTask) {
                WellnessTaskItem(
                    onClose = { showTask = false },
                    taskName = "Have you taken your 15 minute walk today?",
                )
            }
            Text("You've had $count glasses.")
        }

        Row(Modifier.padding(top = 8.dp)) {
            Button(onClick = { count++ }, enabled = count < 10) { Text("Add one") }
            Button(onClick = { count = 0 }, Modifier.padding(start = 8.dp)) {
                Text("Clear water count")
            }
        }
    }
}

Tried using rememberSaveable but it didn't work.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The general idea is to hoist the state to somewhere higher up in the compose tree. This usually means to place the state in the composable that calls the current composable and pass the value of the state as a parameter. However, in your specific case, it suffices to just hoist it out of the if by moving it one line up:
var count by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
var showTask by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }

if (count > 0) {
    if (showTask) {
        WellnessTaskItem(...)
    }
    Text(...)
}

This way the state will never leave the compose tree and therefore the value will not be lost during recompositions.
